# Authorization Code Grant return invalid_grant

Tags: vb.net, curl, oauth, docusignapi

I am trying to implement DocuSign OAuth by Authorization Code Grant.

Firstly what I am trying to do:

- Make GET request to https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=token&scope=signature&client_id=71d5e08f-299d-480a-9520-74d2e5083008&state=a39fh23hnf23&redirect_uri=http://localhost/callback

When i have got token i am trying to make POST request by CURL

curl -i -v -d "grant_type=authorization_code&code=eyJ0eXAiOiJNVCIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2Iiwia2lkIjoiNjgxODVmZjEtNGU1MS00Y2U5LWFmMWMtNjg5ODEyMjAzMzE3In0.AQkAAAABAAYABwAABDYucBzVSAgAAJC8dXAc1UgCAISmNWgyUw9Hlk8ldzq-z2gNACQAAAA3MWQ1ZTA4Zi0yOTlkLTQ4MGEtOTUyMC03NGQyZTUwODMwMDgVAAEAAAASAAAAAAAYAAEAAAAFAAAAIAAABDYucBzVSA.0yPv4mlsiuab6ZlC11k_s9rR5gLO0Z1aEoHlyXrE30ba3LD6qBaqqVFcdQDJ3tagx0-6rg48fENjpkglkELnZG7tmF2AZYR98DUYgbot4OMnj0Y0Q-QhhqLvOe6SJmYxfYqCxBC03FVBjH9gTvCVD7kb0msN23-pw5WGRi5p209gNhr-YDv0wb9jwMJdNC-z5QSW0D5qgkbP5HKjIxgITG_qNCyO3CWPvlJIG8u1Wh1oB-EL4JI5fUZSNlipEpZRKG0jU9cbZbO8DaeEhZzfL54wc38r4luN-2XJx1yL48p4HgNP2ujWJAIJiJpy_-TnmMHTHzp3YTaPB7Swus_Leg" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Authorization: Basic NzFkNWUwOGYtMjk5ZC00ODBhLTk1MjAtNzRkMmU1MDgzMDA4OjY5MDcwMGI4LTAxMmQtNGU1My05N2FlLTVhNmFkNjg3OWVkYg==" -X POST https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token

And always I am getting the same message : "invalid_grant"

I have checked all params twice, and i know about that question [DocuSign authorization code grant flow gets invalid_grant error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39881341/docusign-authorization-code-grant-flow-gets-invalid-grant-error) about the same situation, it is not marked as answered

Can anyone explan me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing two type Authorization Code Grant and Implicit Code Grant, in your first GET URL, you are passing `response_type=token` instead it should be `response_type=code`, once you will change response_type from token to code then it will work.